# Подскажите пожалуйста как создать массив строк для выгрузки в них данных из файлов для дальнейшего использования. Хочу создать своеобразную БД на С++

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{SetConsoleCP (1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
    ofstream F;
    fstream F3, F4, F5;
    F3.open("countAccount.txt");
    F4.open("setName.txt");
    F5.open("setPassword.txt");
    F.open("datebase.txt");
    string userName, password;
    string setName;
    string setPassword;
    string rusLiter = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖХИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    string rusLiterSimbol = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖХИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ/\<>?*|:;";
    bool condition = false;
    int action, countName, iName, resultName, resultPas, i, countLit = 0, countLitPas  = 0, notRep;
    
    F3 >> countName;
    for(i = 0; i < countName; i++)
            F4 >> setName[i];
    for(i = 0; i < countName; i++)
        F5 >> setPassword[i];
    
    cout << "1.Вход\n2.Регистрация\n3.Выход\nВыберите действие:  "; cin >> action;
```

Comment: `vector<string>`, например...

Comment: Без шуток, советую начать осваивать программирование пошагово: как создать массив --> строк --> для выгрузки в них данных --> из файлов. "Хочу создать своеобразную БД на С++" - а это значительно потом.

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо